# How to transfer php session variables from a page to an iframe inside the page

Tags: php, session, variables, iframe

So I have a webpage with session variables, for example one variable is:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'testname';
```

I have an iframe within the page, and want to use this session variable in it. For a start, I am trying to just do this:

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

I have not found a way to transmit the session variable into the iframe page.

INFORMATION (IMPORTANT!):
I have used `session_start();` on both the main page and the iframe page, and I have also tried using `session_write_close();` on both pages. The pages are in the same domain. Please answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the page in the iframe in the same site as the parent page? In other words, can they share the same session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What ever page is referenced in the iframe, if it exists on your the same domain will have access to the same session information on the hosting site so long as that page has session_start() called on it.

Example.

```
  page1.php 
  <?php
       session_start();
       $_SESSION["HELLO"] = "WORLD";
  ?>
  <html>
      <iframe src='page2.php'/>
  </html>

  page2.php
  <?php 
        session_start();
        echo "HELLO ".$_SESSION["HELLO"]; // will output HELLO WORLD
```

This is only true for sites that have access to the same cookies and the same session store.

Comment: I am using the same domain.

Comment: are they both being accessed via the same protocol http / https

Comment: yes, they are. I believe I have magically fixed the problem although I haven't really changed anything... thanks anyway :)

Comment: And what if not in the same domain ?